# Swift scoping issue, add variable inside the alamofire request function, but the variable seem lost when it goes outside the function

Tags: swift

When I try to add GeoPoint which I got through calling my API, I can print it inside the Alamofire.request, but it has nothing outside of it. Also, at the end of the function, there is nothing to return.
the first print work correctly, but the second print, which at the end of the function, it prints nothing.

```
//function used to get geopoints info
func loadParkingLotsInfo() -> [[GeoPoint]]?{
    
    var locations: [[GeoPoint]] = []
    var location: [GeoPoint] = []
    
    let header: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Subscriber-UUID": "jgwqjdgjhqwhqhwjgdhqwdhqwd",
        "Trx-ID": "651426512"
    ]
    
    Alamofire.request(ip + "/api/zones/all", method: .get, headers: header).responseJSON{
        (DataResponse) in
        if let data = DataResponse.data{
            do {
                let json = try JSON(data: data)
                for (_, subjson) in json["data"]{
                    location = []
                    for (_, geoinfo) in subjson["geopoints"]{
                        let latitude = geoinfo["latitude"].doubleValue
                        let longitude = geoinfo["longitude"].doubleValue
                        let id = geoinfo["id"].intValue
                            
                            let geoPoint = GeoPoint(id: id, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                            location.append(geoPoint)
                    }
                    locations.append(location)
                    for loc in locations{
                        for point in loc{
                            print(point.id)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }catch{
                
            }
        }
    }
    for loc in locations{
        for point in loc{
            print(point.id)
        }
    }
    return locations
}
```

Comment: You should read up on *asynchronous execution* first.

Comment: As a hint, `Alamofire.request` runs on a background thread, i.e. it doesn't block the calling thread while the request executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a completion handler as a parameter, something like this:

```
func loadParkingLotsInfo(completion:@escaping (_ locations: [[GeoPoint]]) -> Void) {

var locations: [[GeoPoint]] = []
var location: [GeoPoint] = []

let header: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Subscriber-UUID": "jgwqjdgjhqwhqhwjgdhqwdhqwd",
    "Trx-ID": "651426512"
]

Alamofire.request(ip + "/api/zones/all", method: .get, headers: header).responseJSON{
    (DataResponse) in
    if let data = DataResponse.data{
        do {
            let json = try JSON(data: data)
            for (_, subjson) in json["data"]{
                location = []
                for (_, geoinfo) in subjson["geopoints"]{
                    let latitude = geoinfo["latitude"].doubleValue
                    let longitude = geoinfo["longitude"].doubleValue
                    let id = geoinfo["id"].intValue
                        
                        let geoPoint = GeoPoint(id: id, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                        location.append(geoPoint)
                }
                locations.append(location)
                for loc in locations{
                    for point in loc{
                        print(point.id)
                    }
                }
                completion(locations)
            }
            
        }catch{
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to call this function in the view controller then?

Comment: for example, I want to get those geopoints to draw a polygon overlay to my map view